# Plotting graph using pandas dataframe for multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file with name "file.csv"

```
,DATE,DAY,OPEN,2PM,CLOSE,STATUS
0,2021-05-18,Tuesday,538.8,530.45,530.8,0
1,2021-05-19,Wednesday,530.65,532.6,536.85,0
2,2021-05-20,Thursday,536.95,537.05,536.35,1
3,2021-05-21,Friday,538.0,538.2,537.55,1
4,2021-05-24,Monday,537.3,535.05,532.85,1
5,2021-05-25,Tuesday,535.9,531.35,529.65,1
6,2021-05-26,Wednesday,532.95,530.55,532.1,0
7,2021-05-27,Thursday,532.95,529.65,529.85,0
```

I am using pandas to convert it to df.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("file.csv")
```

df output can be seen as

[image]

There is a  "STATUS" column that has 1 and 0 values.

I want to plot Monday to Friday from DAY column on the graph with values of STATUS column (i.e. 0 or 1). I want to see how many percentages of 0 or 1 were present on each days.

I do not know how to use these 2 columns for plotting such a graph.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you want to plot

Comment: What do you mean "probability of 1/0 status mentioned on the graph"? The goal of the plot is unclear what information are you trying to visualize?

Comment: @Hemesh: Status column has 0 and 1 values. I want to plot them for days columns

Comment: @Henry Ecker: I want to plot pie chart or any graph wich can show different relationships of days column and status column

Comment: That's a super broad question. There are many visualizations that can show a relationship between two columns. What kind of pie chart? One for 0s and one for 1s?? Again, what information are you trying to visualize? What do you want the plot to demonstrate?

Comment: @Henry Ecker : at the moment, I want to see on different days like Mon, Tue, Wed, etc , what is the probability of 1 or 0. How many 1's and how many 0's do come on Monday, Tue, etc

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, do you want something like this:

```
df.groupby('DAY')['STATUS'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack().plot.bar()
```

Output:

[image]

Pie chart:

```
df.groupby('DAY')['STATUS'].value_counts(normalize=True).unstack(0).plot.pie(subplots=True, figsize=(15,8))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: if OP wants to reorder the days, add something like `.reindex(['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday'])`

Comment: can we plot pie chat with DAYS, and STATUS?

Comment: Pie chart generally track one metric.   5 pie charts by day with status?

Comment: @Scott Boston: aaha and how to keep csv file name in the plot?

Comment: Add an annotation to the plot.

Answer (score 1):

To plot `STATUS` per `DAY` in pie form, one idea is a [nested pie chart](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/nested_pie.html), e.g.:

```py
days = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday']
g = df.groupby('DAY')['STATUS'].value_counts().unstack().fillna(0).reindex(days)

# STATUS       0    1
# DAY                
# Monday     0.0  1.0
# Tuesday    1.0  1.0
# Wednesday  2.0  0.0
# Thursday   0.0  1.0
# Friday     0.0  1.0
```

```py
# outer ring (DAY)
size = 0.2
plt.pie(g.sum(axis=1), radius=1,
        startangle=90, counterclock=False,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'),
        labels=g.index)

# inner ring (STATUS)
values = g.values.ravel()
status = g.columns.tolist() * len(g)
colors = ['#999', '#333'] * len(g)
plt.pie(values, radius=1 - size, colors=colors,
        startangle=90, counterclock=False,
        wedgeprops=dict(width=size, edgecolor='w'),
        labels=[status[i] if values[i] else '' for i in range(len(values))],
        labeldistance=0.6)
```

[image: nested pies for status per day]